# A sequence of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ pointwise bounded at rationals

Tags: real-analysis

I made up my own question:

> If $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ pointwise bounded at rationals, then there exists a convergent subsequence $f_{n_k}\to f$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

My attempt:

By Arzela-Ascoli we find a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ that pointwise converges at every point of $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $f$ be the pointwise limit on $\mathbb{Q}$. Is it possible to choose $f$ to be continuous on $\mathbb{Q}$? If so, then we can extend it continuously to $\mathbb{R}$, and $f_{n_k}\to f$ at every point.

Comment: $f_n(x) = \sin(nx)$ should be a counterexample; in particular it invalidates your suggestion of using Arzela-Ascoli, as it is not equicontinuous. If you add an equicontinuity hypothesis then your question becomes pretty straightforward: if you have a uniform bound on the sup norm of the restrictions to the rationals, then you get a corresponding uniform bound on the sup norm of the unrestricted functions. Then the result follows directly from Arzela-Ascoli.

Comment: Also, you can not extend a function that is continuous on $\Bbb{Q}$  to a continuous function on $\Bbb{R}$ in general, e.g. $f(x) =0$ for $x <\sqrt{2}$ and $1$ otherwise (on $\Bbb{Q}$). You need some form of "locally uniform continuity".